# How to properly block code execution in Python?

Tags: python, events, gevent

I need to block the execution of a Greenlet till a condition occurs, like the following:

```
...
while not some_condition:
    gevent.sleep(0.00000000000001)
...
```

This approach is very cpu intensive. If I change `gevent.sleep(0.000000000001)` to `gevent.sleep(0.1)`, cpu usage drops to 1/10. But this time, in the worst case scenario, code will continue its execution 0.1 seconds after `some_condition` occurs, not right after.

So, how can I make my greenlet pause its execution until a condition occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gevent.event.Event` solved my problem: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.event.html